Storing import.meta.url in a variable throws Uncaught SyntaxError
Im using jest in an angular 17 project and I have several web workers which I initialize. I would like to mock away import.meta.url as import.meta is not available in the test environment. I have the following in the constructor of my component:
this.myWorker = new Worker(
   new URL('../workers/my-test.worker', import.meta.url),
);

Which works well. However I cant run the tests.
Error when running tests (the error provides a solution but I dont want to change my jest config and rather prefer to mock this property away if possible):
error TS1343: The 'import.meta' meta-property is only allowed when the '--module' option is 'es2020', 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext'.

Therefore I tried storing import.meta.url in a variable (tried inline and static in component level as well as completely moving in a separate file), and consuming that variable for initializing my worker so that I can mock that variable away.
However, this throws error in runtime which I dont know why. Here is a minimal example in the constructor of my component:
const url = import.meta.url;
this.myWorker = new Worker(
   new URL('../workers/my-test.worker', url),
);

And it results in the following error in the console:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at

However I dont understand this behavior. Any leads are appreciated.

The "Unexpected token '<' (at" bit would point to an html error response page from your server, certainly the produced URL isn't correct. As for why it's not working that way, it's hard to say, but you might want to log url to check what it outputs. Also note that there is a import.meta.resolve() method, instead of passing a full URL object.

@Kaiido I have logged the urls and they are identical. However i have not tried import.meta.resolve(...). I will give an update.

@Kaiido Seems in my environment .resolve(...) cant be resolved. But I also tried logging the value of import.meta.url and using the value directly as a string. Which resulted in the same syntax error!
